# How to make cloned repo shared?

Tags: git

How can I make my cloned repo to be cloned by others via ssh, so that my team members can push the changes and in the same time I can pull changes from origin.

master repo (other site) clone via git --> my repo <--> clone by my team mates

--> only pull

<--> pull and push

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to *push* changes into a repo that has a checked-out working copy around it. (You can, however, *pull* into a repository with an associated working copy) Therefore, the first thing to do is to create a bare clone with `git clone --bare`.

This clone has to be made reachable by you and your team members, a nice overview of all the possible way to do that is [8 ways to share your git repository](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/).

Do note:

- If you have this clone on your own machine, you have to do a "normal" clone of this repository to create your own working copy, you can't work directly in the bare repository (by definition).
- Since you now have two git repositories to manage (the bare clone and your working copy) it's a bit more work to keep everything in sync. If it's okay that you pull everything from your team members instead of having them push to you, you can get away with using only your normal working copy, or a lot less overhead.

Here's what it'd look like:

```
(other site) --> (bare clone) <--> (your working clone)
                              <--> (your team mates)
```

With only pulls, it's slightly simpler:

```
(other site) --> (your working clone) <-- (your team mates)
```

The push-pull setup does have a clear and obvious master.

Comment: Thanks a lot will check the 8 way. Liked this, 1. create bare clone repo   2. all team members (including owner) clone  3. members can push and pull  4. owner can push to bare clone and to its origin.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you access the repo, you can use ssh, git, http or simple file share.

I use file share (Windows), since all developers are in one networks. So, as soon as you cloned the repo and share repository folder. Another developer can:

```
git remote add some_name //you_ip_address/name_of_repo.git
git fetch some_name
```

If another developer has no such repository, he first can clone from you

```
git clone //you_ip_address/name_of_repo.git
```

Comment: Probably i need to rephrase my question. We have two teams working together, I have cloned their repo by git protocol (read only access). I want this repo to act as master for my team to clone via ssh and push the changes back to me. in the same time i will be pulling the changes from the other team.

Comment: I don't see any problems with that. Just provide access to you repo to the rest of the team, so they can clone it.

Comment: Really, thanks , sorry for the dump question :) . How will i give access to them ? I need like --shared=group in init command.

Comment: As I said, I'm doing that on Windows, so I can controll access rights for Shared Folder. I set only Read for Everyone.. and Read/Write for developers group;